# Why does Google app engine recognize URLs, phone numbers and similar as special data types?

Tags: google-app-engine, database-design, data-structures, google-cloud-datastore

Just wondering... why does Google app engine recognize "special" string [data types](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/dataclasses.html#Core_Value_Types) such as Link, [Email](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Email.html), [PhoneNumber](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/PhoneNumber.html), [PostalAddress](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/PostalAddress.html) and such? They seem to be simple text types, and don't even have any helper methods which would, for example, extract host/port information from Link.

What design decision would warrant such a distinction?

And, to continue with a bit more down-to-earth concerns, what benefit do those data types bring to programmers? Why should I use them instead of simple Strings?

Comment: possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856126/app-engine-why-are-there-phonenumber-link-rating-etc-classes

Comment: I think we all should use only 1's and 0's. Possibly just zeros.

Comment: I agree that this question is a duplicate, and I agree with the answer given in the other question: they are semantic types that carry inherent meaning. It gives you a clue as to what data is contained in them and thus what to do with the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Nick has already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856126/app-engine-why-are-there-phonenumber-link-rating-etc-classes/1856281#1856281), when converted to xml with `.to_xml()`, these properties have different behaviors. Have a look at [Gdata docs](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/1.0/elements.html#gdPhoneNumber) for more details.