# Why use PostalAddress property in Gql?

Tags: google-app-engine, gql, gqlquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why Email, Username, PostalCode, etc as entities in GAE Datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814182/why-email-username-postalcode-etc-as-entities-in-gae-datastore)

App Engine Data store has this property "PostalAddress" but what is the purpose of using it?

Here it is in the docs: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#PostalAddress

I have addresses that I want to store and I was thinking if I ever wanted to get the cities or zip codes I'd be able to easily query them if I stored them in different column fields. Or is there a way to extract the zip code or city/state or street line from the postal address property without having to use regex on it...

Anyone know how use this property?

Answer (score 4):

It's basically just a String property. No validation is performed or any kind of structure is assumed. They probably used it in order to support the gd:postalAddress element.

https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/1.0/elements?hl=el#gdPostalAddress